# Two pointers in ROM hardware implementation

Tags: memory, memory-management, verilog, hardware, rom

ROM is implemented by case statement to store fixed values in it and read them whenever we need.

But how can I read two values at the same clock cycle ??

Answer (score 2):

It is always useful to show at least part of your code. I assume you have something like this:

```
case (adrs)
8'h00 : dout <= 8h01;
8'h01 : dout <= 8h03;
8'h02 : dout <= 8h07;
```

The only solution is to make two identical case statements but it is easier to instance the same ROM twice.

Alternative is to make a memory and initialise it.

```
reg [7:0] mem [0:255];
... // initialise memory e.g
... // using initial with for loop and case statement    
   always @(posedge clk)
   begin
      dout1< = mem[adrs1];
      dout2< = mem[adrs2];
   end
```

I assume this is for an FPGA so look at the vendor manual how to make a pre-loaded RAM. (Which is on fact a ROM as long as you don't write to it)